# Y a-t-il une différence de registre entre « commencer » et « se mettre » ?

Tags: lexique, registre

Y a-t-il une différence de registre entre « commencer » et « se mettre » ?

Peut-on employer l’un ou l’autre indifféremment ?

Answer (score 2):

Est-ce que tu parles de l'expression « se mettre à ... » ? Si oui, on emploie cette expression quand on ne veut pas utiliser commencer.

> Eg.: Les hommes se mettent au travail = Les hommes commencent le travail.

Comment: Sa question est surtout de savoir s'il y a une différence de registre.

Comment: aah, je vois. je crois qu'il y en a

Comment: Au début je pensais que "se mettre à" était un peu familier, mais en y réfléchissant, on doit trouver des textes littéraires utilisant cette forme (*les cieux se mirent alors à cracher des éclairs*).

Comment: Je pense que la seule différence est que « se mettre » peut avoir un tout autre sens, comme dans « se mettre à dos » ou « se mettre en règle » alors que « commencer » a toujours la même signification. Donc on peut toujours remplacer « commencer » par « se mettre à » mais l’inverse n’est pas vrai.

Comment: @ Simon ça peut être considéré comme familier et soutenu. ceci est possible parce qu' on peut employer le registre soutenu et familier dans des textes littéraires.

Comment: Un cas de _fausse nuance_? Je crois que les deux sont complètement équivalents, je ne vois pas de différence de registre.

Comment: Concernant le registre, il s’agit du registre courant dans les deux cas.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Y a-t-il une différence de registre entre « commencer » et « se mettre » ?

**Oui** si l'on compare « **commencer de** » à « **se mettre à** », mais **non** si l'on compare « **commencer à** » à « **se mettre à** ».

Le plus rare « **commencer de** + verbe », souvent utilisé pour éviter un hiatus, est généralement considéré comme étant d'un registre plus soutenu que « **commencer à** + verbe ».

Références:
[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/commencer)

> b) ***Commencer de* est plus fréq. dans la lang. soignée que dans la lang. usuelle ou fam.**
> ...
> d) Afin d'éviter l'hiatus, **l'usage soigné tend parfois à employer *de*** lorsque commencer est à une forme qui se terminera par une voyelle, ou devant les verbes commençant par une voyelle. 2. **Dans l'emploi fam.** (supra H. Bazin et Simenon) **on ne rencontre jamais *de***.

[OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2316)

> L’expression *commencer à* est cependant beaucoup plus répandue et courante que *commencer de*, **qui est aujourd’hui sentie comme soutenue, littéraire**.

Langue soutenue:

> Il **commença d'avoir** faim. → On évite le double hiatus
>
> Aucun bruit n'annonce le jour, sinon le grincement des girouettes sous la brise de terre, et de la plume sur le cahier où vont **commencer de** s'écrire, ce matin même, Les Travailleurs de la mer. *Bertrand Poirot-Delpech* - [Victor Hugo et la mer](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/victor-hugo-et-la-mer-celebration-du-bicentenaire-de-la-naissance-de-victor-hugo) - Académie Française - 2002

Langue usuelle:

> Il **commença à avoir** faim. → [a.a.a]

Cette différence est controversée, voir ["A" ET "DE" APRES "COMMENCER" DANS LE SCHEMA " V1 A / DE V2 "](http://www.seinan-gu.ac.jp/%7Etrubert/A-DE.html) (Thierry Trubert-Ouvrard).

« **Se mettre** » est un peu moins précis que « **commencer** »<sup>1</sup> et peut donc être considéré d'un registre légèrement moins soutenu que ce dernier, mais la différence est infime et surtout très relative. C'est l'expression complète qui déterminera véritablement le registre utilisé.

Par exemple « Tu commences à me les briser » est certainement d'un registre moins soutenu que « Hier, nous nous mîmes à l'œuvre de bonne heure » ;-)

Autant « se mettre » que « commencer » peuvent en effet apparaître dans des phrases de registre soutenu, courant ou familier. Ce ne sont tout simplement pas des « marqueurs » de registre.

Il existe des verbes pouvant remplacer « commencer / se mettre à » qui sont eux, clairement associés à un registre donné:

> Il serait plaisant que vous **entamiez** votre labeur ! (soutenu)
>
> Il faut **te mettre** au travail ! (courant)
>
> Il faut **commencer** ton travail ! (courant)
>
> Faut **te foutre** au boulot ! (familier)

---

> 2. Peut-on employer l’un ou l’autre indifféremment ?

**Non**, pas toujours. Une nuance de sens est possible : « commencer » peut indiquer la première étape d'un processus graduel (anglais *begin*) alors que « se mettre à » indique plutôt un changement d'état, une bascule (anglais *start*).

> Il **commence** à dormir : décrit le début de l'endormissement, il s'endort
>
> Il **se met** à dormir : il était réveillé, il est endormi.
>
> Il **commence** à parler russe : son apprentissage de la langue russe commence à porter ses fruits.
>
> Il **se met** à parler russe : il parlait dans une autre langue et subitement, il parle en russe.

Cette différence peut être neutralisée par la présence d'un adverbe:

> Il s'est mis lentement à se lever = Il commença à se lever
>
> Soudain, il commença à dormir = il s'est mis à dormir

Il existe des cas où « commencer » ne peut pas se substituer à « se mettre » :

> Il se met à poil→ <s>Il commence à poil</s>
>
> Il se met au courant → <s>Il commence au courant</s>
>
> Tu t'es mis à dormir pendant une heure → <s>Tu as commencé à dormir pendant une heure</s>

« Commencer à se mettre » est possible mais « se mettre à commencer » est rarissime:

> Tout le monde commence à se mettre au travail. → <s>Tout le monde se met à commencer de travailler</s>

Parfois, « se mettre à » peut difficilement traduire commencer:

> Il a commencé sa vie en Grèce → <s>Il s'est mis à vivre en Grèce.</s>
>
> Il commence à être célèbre → <s>Il se met à être célèbre</s>
>
> Je commence à être sourd → <s>Je me met à être sourd</s>
>
> C'est vous qui commencerez en premier → <s>C'est vous qui vous mettrez en premier</s>
>
> Les problèmes commencent à être résolus → <s>Les problèmes se mettent à être résolus</s>
>
> Ça commence à se savoir → <s>Ça se met à se savoir</s>

À la négative, les sens sont différents:

> Je n'ai pas commencé à manger (= pas encore)
>
> Je ne me suis pas mis à manger (= c'est faux, pas du tout)

Une thèse de doctorat analyse en profondeur les différences entre « se mettre à » et « commencer » : **La construction inchoative *se mettre à:* syntaxe, sémantique et grammaticalisation, *Filip Verroens*, Universiteit Gent, 2011**

<sup>1</sup> [TLFI](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mettre):

> Rem. gén. 1. Dans la lang. soutenue et notamment dans la lang. écrite, on emploie souvent un verbe plus précis que mettre ou **se mettre**.

Comment: Avez-vous des exemples ou commencer peut-être utilisé avec _de_ ou _à_ indifféremment (donc le sens doit être exactement le même), mais où l'on peut percevoir la différence de registre? Idem pour la _précision_ de _commencer_.

Comment: My sense is also that, difference in meaning aside, *se mettre à* is slightly more soutenu than *commencer à*. A couple of book examples: [here](http://ow.ly/YeIf308LByz) notice "Je me mis à faire des calculs et je reconnus qu'au prix où l'on avait la terre dans ce moment-là, ..." where it's comfortably in the passé simple. Meanwhile, [here](http://ow.ly/MhVP308LBHk), *commencer* sits snugly in a passage of not terribly high register (though not informal, either). Of course, a wider sample is needed, but that's my intuition. :)

Comment: La forme _commencer de_ sonne bizarre maintenant, je dirais. _Il commença d'avoir faim_? oui, pourquoi pas.

Comment: @jlliagre - la nuance _commencer à_ / _commencer de_ est très intéressante, mais je crois que c'est un élargissement de la question de l'OP, qui porte simplement sur _commencer_ et _se mettre_, et si l'un ou l'autre induit un langage de registre différent.

Comment: @jlliagre - link pour 1-TLFI (la référence)?

Comment: @Frank *Commencer de* peut s'utiliser partout où *commencer à* est possible mais il s'agit d'un usage littéraire et soigné qui peut donc surprendre. Références ajoutées pour tous les points commentés. La question porte effectivement sur *commencer* et *se mettre* mais considérant qu'elle porte sur le registre de ces verbes, il ne me paraît pas du tout hors sujet de préciser que *commencer* peut s'utiliser avec deux prépositions différentes sachant que le registre résultant est notoirement différent.

Comment: Ce n'est pas hors sujet, et c'est intéressant. C'est un _élargissement_ car le coeur de la question porte sur _commencer_ et _se mettre_, alors que les deux tiers de votre réponse (grosso modo) portent sur la distinction _commencer à_ / _commencer de_.

Comment: La remarque générale 1 de TLFI ne semble pas se rapporter explicitement au cas _se mettre_ / _commencer_, mais plutôt à des situations où l'on met un objet dans un autre: "_Ainsi insérer, introduire ou loger peuvent se substituer à mettre dans + compl. de lieu, appliquer ou poser à mettre sur, revêtir ou chausser à mettre (un vêtement, des souliers), s'installer à se mettre + prép. + compl. de lieu._". On ne peut pas nécessairement en déduire que _commencer_ est plus précis que _se mettre_. La référence ne soutient pas bien l'argument.

Comment: @Frank Oui, c'est parce que la différence de registre se situe là. Il n'y a pas de différence de registre significative, voire même pas de différence de registre du tout, entre *commencer à* et *se mettre à* isolés. Il y a en revanche une nuance de sens qu'il ne faut pas ignorer; par exemple entre « il commence à me gonfler » et « il se met à me gonfler », « il commence à parler russe » et « il se met à parler russe ».

Comment: @Frank Pour la remarque générale, je pensais par exemple à « se mettre à genoux » où il faut attendre ce qui suit la préposition « à » pour comprendre le sens de « se mettre à » alors qu'avec « commencer », il n'y a pas de confusion possible.

Comment: J'aurais vu la nuance dans l'autre sens (pour l'exemple de l'endormissement): _se mettre à_ étant plus progressif, probablement par associations avec des expressions proches. _commencer_ serait plus neutre, mais _se mettre à_ contiendrait une nuance de progressivité. Avec _commencer_, si on veut évoquer une progression dans le début de qqch, on ajouterait par exemple _à peine_ (?)

Comment: NB: la question est sur le _registre_. Mais tous ces élargissements sont intéressants, bien sûr. Pour cette raison, ces longues chaînes de commentaires ne devraient pas être enlevées. Elles peuvent être intéressantes pour ceux qui veulent creuser et voir différentes opinions.

Comment: Dans le très bel exemple (Victor Hugo et la mer) ci-dessus, après "...le grincement...de la plume sur le cahier où vont commencer de", le choix de 's'écrire' s'impose, il est bloqué par le contexte avant. Sur un cahier, avec une plume qui grince, que peut-on faire d'autre que d'écrire? Commencer à est plus courant parce que 'à' sert à présenter ce qui suit et qui n'est pas rendu évident par le contexte avant. Cf. Le français déchiffré Clé du langage et des langues Henri Adamczewski.

Answer (score 2):

Si la question est: "en gardant exactement le même sens et les mêmes mots dans la phrase mais en changeant seulement *commencer à* par *se mettre à*, obtient-on une phrase dans un autre registre?", je crois que la réponse est ***non***, *en général*.

Je ne crois pas que *se mettre à* et *commencer à* portent en eux, de façon ***intrinsèque***, une nuance de *registre*: nous n'avons pas de règle qui dirait que remplacer simplement *commencer à* par *se mettre à* (sans aucun autre changement) dans une phrase changerait *automatiquement* le registre de cette phrase (ou l'inverse). On peut construire des phrases dans le même registre avec *commencer à* aussi bien qu'avec *se mettre à*.

Je crois que la différence de registre perçue dans les exemples proposés est plutôt *extrinsèque*, c'est-à-dire qu'elle provient du reste de la phrase et du contexte, du ton employé... Il est possible que *se mettre à* sonne mieux dans certains contextes, ou que *commencer à* soit obligatoire dans certaines expressions (et vice-versa). Mais ces différences sont dues à l'usage ou au contexte, plutôt que portées entièrement par le verbe *commencer à* ou *se mettre à* lui-même. Sans aucun contexte, *commencer à* et *se mettre à* sont a priori équivalents.

En général, la langue Française a certainement des synonymes dans différents registres (*chiottes* / *toilettes*, *caisse* / *voiture*, *bouffer* / *manger* ...), mais le phénomène n'est pas aussi sophistiqué et systématique que dans des langues telles que le Japonais, où l'on trouve des séries de variantes pour un même mot suivant le registre de langage: *kuu → taberu → meshi-agaru* (manger), *aru → gozaru* (être), ... En Japonais, le registre de langue est *intrinsèquement* contenu dans le choix de *aru* ou *gozaru*. Même sans aucun autre contexte, utiliser l'un ou l'autre détermine complètement le registre, sans changer le sens. Je ne crois pas que ce soit le cas pour *commencer à* et *se mettre à*.

Note: [TLFI](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mettre) définit *se mettre à* ainsi: "*Commencer à faire quelque chose; entrer dans un processus.*", i.e. en utilisant *commencer à* (!)

Comment: C'est aussi mon impression. Est-ce que ce n'est pas _s'y mettre_ qui est un peu moins soutenu ?

Comment: @AlexandreFlak - ma réponse milite pour un certain agnosticisme dans les cas où un contexte n'est pas fourni :-)

Answer (score 2):

Il me semble que 'se mettre' souligne plus le déclenchement de ce qui est présenté à sa suite. Comme s'il s'agissait d'en présenter surtout le point de départ.

Alors qu'avec 'commencer', j'ai l'impression qu'une suite possible est déjà envisagée, que 'commencer' laisse déjà entendre que ce qui suit va continuer.

Si mon intuition est exacte, on peut donc parfois parler de la même chose de deux points de vue différents. Il faudrait confronter ceci à un solide corpus d'exemples.

Quant à la différence entre 'commencer/continuer à' et 'commencer/continuer de', elle rappelle celle que l'on trouve en anglais entre 'begin/continue to' et 'begin/continue V-ing'. (V=verb)

Dans les phrases où l'on a à effectuer ce type de choix, on se retrouve avec un premier verbe (V1) à ou de (qu'il faut savoir choisir) suivi d'un deuxième verbe (V2).

V1 et V2 sont chacun porteur d'information.

Lorsque le poids informationnel de V2 est plus important (nouveau) que celui de V1, on aura 'V1 à V2'. Cas le plus courant.

Par contre, lorsque c'est l'inverse on aura 'V1 de V2'.

Exemple (cité par Adamcweski qui a mis au jour ce point de grammaire):

Pas de changement dans les jours à venir. Il va continuer de faire beau jusqu'à la fin de la semaine.

L'information 'faire beau jusqu'à la fin de la semaine' n'est pas vraiment nouvelle, elle est déjà contenue dans 'pas de changement dans les jours à venir' C'est pour signaler cela que 'de' apparaît.

Si l'on observe maintenant le magnifique exemple cité par Jiliagre:

'Aucun bruit n'annonce le jour, sinon le grincement des girouettes sous la brise de terre, et de la plume sur le cahier où vont commencer de s'écrire, ce matin même, les Travailleurs de la Mer. (Bertrand Poirot-Delpech / Victor Hugo et la Mer.)

Le verbe 'commencer' a ici plus de poids informationnel que 's'écrire' dont le sens est anticipé par ce qui précède: 'le grincement de la plume sur le cahier'.
C'est la raison pour laquelle 'de' apparaît dans cet exemple.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne pense pas qu'on puisse noter une quelconque différence de registre entre ces deux expressions . Il est possible qu'en pratique "se mettre à" soit utilisée de manière plus fréquente dans un registre plus soutenu , mais la différence principale selon moi réside surtout dans la définition que l'on attache à ces expressions. Dans mon interprétation de ces expressions , "se mettre à" est une action antérieure à "commencer". Je voit la première expression comme une préparation à la deuxième. 
J'ai conscience que cette interprétation est très personnelle , peut sembler erronée ou hors sujet mais dans un registre soutenu les expressions sont souvent plus précises que dans un registre courant voir familier.

Le choix de l'expression à utiliser dépend selon moi plus de son adéquation à la situation que de l'appartenance de la dite expression à un registre particulier.